# Asp.net onclick event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with Asp.Net.  asp:button's OnClick event like the below.  I would like to have jquery call "Save_Click' event.  Is it possible?

**Home.aspx.cs code**

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //code to update database  goes here....
    }
```

**jquery code**

```
$("#ABC").click(function() {
        $($get("Save")).click();
        return false;
    });
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:Button id="Save" runat="server" Text="Save Details" OnClick="Save_Click"  />
<input id="ABC" type="button" value="button" />
```

Comment: I think the best solution would be to call an ASP.NET Web Service using jQuery.ajax(). This article should help you: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 2):

Use __doPostBack function:

```
$("#ABC").click(function() {
    __doPostBack('Save');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button id="Save" runat="server" Text="Save Details" OnClientClick="Save_Click"  />
```

This is will work or u can do something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[id$='yourinputbutton']").click(function() {
// Do client side button click stuff here.
});
});
```

Are you looking for Jquery asp.net Button, What exactly you want to acheive?

Comment: OnClientClick will try and run a javascript 'Save_Click' function, not the server-side click event..